# PHP loop not writing text consistently

Tags: php, html, loops

Here's my code snippet:

```
   foreach ($row as $key => $val) {

        echo "<div class='jmp'><b>". htmlentities($key).": </b><br>"
        .htmlentities($val)."</div>\n";
    }
```

Oddly, PHP sometimes output like this:

```
<div class='jmp'><b>HDD_SIZE_GB:</b><br> 143.5</div>
<div class='jmp'><b>HDD_MODEL:b><br> SEAGATE STT14775 </div>
<div class='jmp'><b>HDD_SN:</b><br> 3LN3N0098271QL2</div>
```

Note that the the ending < is missing from "b" element in the middle? What is causing it? There are 500 records in DB. Even more puzzling, it is not consistent. When I refresh the page, that error in that particular row will disappear but the identical error will pop up in other rows. That totally defeats the strict XHTML parsing.

Comment: that a weird problem. What happens if you replace htmlentities with htmlspecialchars?

Comment: I think you need to look at the value of your `$key`

Comment: Did htmlspecialchars.. .again same result. It's weird, no kidding. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: For debugging, have you just done a print_r($row)?

Comment: Also, for strict XHTML, you should change <br> to <br />.

Comment: yes and it looks perfectly normal in print_r($row) - here's the thing - the < sometimes just disappear for no reason. And it's never consistent despite reloading the page with exactly same data.

Comment: additionally, the missing < is inside the echo quotes... so it's PHP, not HTML itself. PHP is not echoing the < for some reason for one or two rows. Why would it fail to echo that? I noticed it happens after a couple of thousand lines.

Comment: Are you sure that is the raw output (try it on the command line, or with lynx)? Sometimes browsers will alter code... Also try to filter out strange code from $key and $var with: `$key = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/', '', $key);`

Comment: You're right, John! It's the browser altering the code, not the output itself! Definitely weird!

Comment: BTW, John, please answer in ANSWER section so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

Are you sure that is the raw output (try it on the command line, or with lynx)? Sometimes browsers will alter code...

Answer (score -3):

How is your array created.
This way it should work as expected

```
$row = array();
$row['HDD_SIZE_GB'] = '143.5';
$row['HDD_MODEL'] = 'SEAGATE STT14775';
$row['HDD_SN'] = '3LN3N0098271QL2';
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? This is just showing a way how to make it work as expected, so maybe the problem lies there